# Python отображение ключей словаря

Tags: python

ДД! В задании происходит добавление/удаление ключей, по итогу нужно вывести динамичный результат в зависимости от изменений через присвоение к переменной res в виде: res = 'Текущий перечень полок: 1, 2, 3.' Как можно отобразить такой вывод динамически, а не записывать вручную?

```
'1': ['2207 876234', '11-2'],
'2': ['10006'],
'3': []
}

def delete_shell():
    number_of_shell = input()
    res = 'На полке есть документа, удалите их перед удалением полки. Текущий перечень полок: 1, 2, 3.'
    if number_of_shell not in directories:
        res = 'Такой полки не существует. Текущий перечень полок: 1, 2, 3.'
    elif directories[number_of_shell] == []:
        del directories[number_of_shell]
        res = 'Полка удалена. Текущий перечень полок: 1, 2.'
    return res
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код, и поясните что в неи не работает так как вам хочется.

Comment: Что это за "ДД"?

Comment: день добрый. драг диллер.

Comment: @strawdog, ДДТ без Т.(дихлордифенил) :)

Answer (score 2):

`list(dict.keys())` - чтобы получить ключи словаря в виде списка. После этого можете делать с ними, что нужно.

Answer (score -1):

Пришлось дописать новую функцию:

```
def make_li_seq(li):
    a = ''
    for i in li:
        if i == li[-1]:
            a += f'{i}.'
        else:
            a += f'{i}, '
    return a


res = f'Текущий перечень: {make_li_seq(li1)}'
```

Comment: За что мы любим Python? Потому что там уже практически всё, сделали за нас.)

Comment: сделали что? на мой вопрос уже есть другое решение, или в чем суть?

Comment: На ваш вопрос ответ внизу. И это работает из коробки, не надо не чего своего изобретать.

Comment: На ваш вопрос ответ внизу. И это работает из коробки, не надо не чего своего изобретать.